# Django traceback error: No module named 'repr'

Tags: python, django

I have been using django perfectly sans problems until today. It was giving me the error on an existing project but I have recently tried to create a new project and I stil get the same errors.
I am on ubuntu 14.04, django 1.7, I use virtualenv and python 3 (alhtough I have tried using a python2 env also).

I get this error:

```
ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp$ 
ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp$ mkvirtualenv djerror
New python executable in djerror/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
cd (djerror)ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp$ cd borrar/
bin/     borrar/  include/ lib/     local/   
(djerror)ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp$ django-admin.py startproject djerror
(djerror)ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp$ cd djerror/
(djerror)ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp/djerror$ ls
djerror  manage.py
(djerror)ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp/djerror$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import collections
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/collections/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from reprlib import recursive_repr as _recursive_repr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reprlib.py", line 3, in <module>
    from repr import *
ImportError: No module named 'repr'
(djerror)ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp/djerror$
```

here is another method which gfives me the same error:

```
ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp$ virtualenv djerror2
New python executable in djerror2/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp$ cd djerror
ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp/djerror$ cd ..
ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp$ cd djerror2
ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp/djerror2$ . bin/activate
(djerror2)ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp/djerror2$ pip list
awsebcli (3.0.10)
cement (2.4.0)
Django (1.7.5)
django-bootstrap3 (5.1.1)
django-braces (1.4.0)
...
stevedore (1.2.0)
virtualenv (12.0.6)
virtualenv-clone (0.2.5)
virtualenvwrapper (4.3.2)
(djerror2)ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp/djerror2$ django-admin.py startproject anothertest
(djerror2)ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp/djerror2$ cd anothertest/
(djerror2)ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp/djerror2/anothertest$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import collections
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/collections/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from reprlib import recursive_repr as _recursive_repr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reprlib.py", line 3, in <module>
    from repr import *
ImportError: No module named 'repr'
(djerror2)ubuntuuser@computer:~/tmp/djerror2/anothertest$
```

What gives?

edit:

This is what I have at the bottom of ~/.bashrc. I have done some changes ever since I installed ubuntu, but I recently changed the bottom two lines for virtualenvwrapper.

```
alias python='python3'

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I think the rest of the file is untouched.

Comment: `repr` is a built-in *function*: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr but there is also: https://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html

Comment: Those tracebacks are showing you importing from both 2.7 and 3.4 libraries, which is clearly wrong. Have you done something to your PYTHONPATH environment variable somewhere?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: Yes, probably (as I said, I am pretty new to this), but not recently. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Brandon / Daniel I have added an edit with my bashrc (which was, in fact edited yesterday). I would love to have your guys' inputs on what I did wrong.

Comment: You've aliased `python` to use Python 3, but your `PYTHONPATH` is pointed at Python 2.7's site-packages. If you're going to use Python 3 by default, you need to change the `PYTHONPATH` to point to its packages, which on Ubuntu/Debian are at `/usr/local/lib/python3.x/dist-packages`

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling around (and especially after reading Brandon and Daniel's comments) I spotted the problem.

I had done something wrong at some point in time which wasn't causing problems until today. The thing is python was loading some modules from the python2 path and others from the python3 path.

To fix it I did the following:

- remove the python3 alias

  - to do this correctly you have to rm python from /usr/bin/ and then point it to python3 sim link
- purge remove python3 and reinstall it.
- reinstall all packages associated to python3, like pip and others

Only then did everything work, though I may have gone overboard, I preferred to do it like this just to be sure.